# BPP and BQP: Optimization Versions?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing

For optimization problems, I found complexity classes analog to some classes for decision problems, e.g. PO and NPO, mirroring P and NP for decision problems in the sense that optimization problems in PO can be solved in polynomial time and verified in polynomial time, respectively.

Are there similar class definitions mirroring BPP and BQP, i.e. classes of optimization problems that could be solved with a probabilistic algorithm or on a quantum computer efficiently?

Comment: The class PO may be used implicitly, but its explicit use is quite uncommon. The class NPO is even less commonly used. On the other hand, approximation algorithms are often randomized, and this is done without any need to define a formal complexity class of optimization problems solvable by randomized algorithms (perhaps up to some error). If you wish, you could define randomized and quantum analogs of PO by analogy.

Comment: Makes sense....